# Saving user color settings of a clicked Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, settings

I have a little problem with saving some properties of my Buttons. The Buttons are small and with a variety of colors. When i press one button, some specified colors are changing... and i want to save them for the next start up. The textbox values i can save them but this ...i can't.

Code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //blueColor.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    //this.Property = Properties.Settings.Default.userColor;
}

private void blueColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bc = new BrushConverter();
    Main.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF007CE4");

    startButton.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF007CE4");
    closeButton.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF007CE4");
    Properties.Settings.Default.userColor = true;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void purpleColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bc = new BrushConverter();
    Main.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF8701B9");
    startButton.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF8701B9");
    closeButton.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF8701B9");
}
```

I think I need the last clicked Button to be saved because I have allot of colors and maybe the .RaiseEvent can help here.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Those 3 little buttons:

- white
- blue
- red

are for changing the look of the program. At every start, the default is back.

Comment: Have you tried looking into XML serialization?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the color as a simple string and `TypeConverter` automatically converts it to type `Brush`. Below is an example.

Binding default value from XAML:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WorkWithSettings.Properties"

<Button Width="100" Height="30"
        Background="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Setting, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Set value from code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.Setting = "#FF007CE4";
}
```

`Note:` Setting - this is just the type of `String`.

More information you can see here:

[TypeConverters and XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx)

`Edit:`

Below I'll show you an example, that I hope will help you.

So, go into the settings of the project: `Project -> Properties -> Parameters`. This opens a window of approximately:

[image]

Here we have a property `ButtonColor`, defined in the settings. For example, I took the `Button`, which changes the background, depending on the color of the pressed button.

In order to property `Background` the synchronize with settings to do, so:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="30" 
        Content="TestButton" 
        Background="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ButtonColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The default background color of white. Now, to set the background color at the button, we change the parameter settings, like this:

```
private void Blue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonColor = "Blue";
}
```

To save changes to the settings, you need to call a method `Save()`:

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Now, the next time you start the program, the color will be the one that was set last.

**`Full example`**

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="WorkWithSettings.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WorkWithSettings.Properties"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Width="100" Height="30" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ButtonColor, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,60,0,0" />
        <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="TestButton" Background="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=ButtonColor, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <WrapPanel>           
            <Button Name="Blue" Width="100" Height="30" Content="BlueColor" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Blue_Click" />
            <Button Name="Red" Width="100" Height="30" Content="RedColor" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Red_Click" />
            <Button Name="White" Width="100" Height="30" Content="WhiteColor" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="White_Click" />
        </WrapPanel>

        <Button Name="Save" Width="60" Height="30" Content="Save" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="Save_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code behind`

```
namespace WorkWithSettings
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void White_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonColor = "White";
        }

        private void Blue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonColor = "Blue";
        }

        private void Red_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.ButtonColor = "Red";
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WorkWithSettings.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

`Output`

[image]

Comment: I don't need to store the colors...there are too many of them,. How about the last clicked button to be saved and loaded on next run ?

Comment: Well, when i press a button, all the colors from inside that method are applied. I want to save that. Something like "blueColor_Click(was pressed...then save it and run on next start)".

Comment: @user2558921: Okay, as I understood: you want to keep the color of the control, and the next time they should be loaded. You have to create every color under the settings parameter of type string (see my example). As I see in your example, you have two colors. Create two parameters with two colors in the settings. You change the value and call Save(), then the changes will be saved.

Comment: It doesn't working, saving the code color is not making it active on next start.

Comment: @user2558921: Show me what you've tried, as well as in my example? For me, it works.

Comment: I can't reproduce your code, even in a blank new wpf with only one button...i get errors or nothing happens, i still need to click that button to take effect. Isn't saving anything. :(   Do i need to insert both codes xaml-cs ?

Comment: The problem is here : Error:The name "Settings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:noia_4__.Properties"......:Background="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=setColor, Mode=TwoWay}"... Can be this done in c# ?

Comment: @user2558921: You need to write the name of of your settings, I do not know how they are called in your project. For you my example works? If it works, maybe you'll find my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, your app is working fine,thank you.I need to fix mine now with your example :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create items in the `Settings` tab of your project that store the information about the color.  I would recommend storing the hex strings.  Then, on `MainForm_Load` retrieve those values.

Make sure to also put the settings in the `User` scope, or else they will reset each time they close the application.