# Variables which need to be live across the application in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application. I need some variables/information not to destroy until user closes that application. Which method is best? *`Static`* Class with *`static`* variables? Moreover what is the best practice in this scenario?

Comment: static variables in a static class

Comment: Maybe a singleton class? This may be a bad idea, especially if you are developing a multithreaded app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, you can use a *static* `Class` with static fields. He is never released, it doesn't have any destructors, and is not involved in garbage collection.

If you want to a normal class stayed alive, you can use the method `GC.KeepAlive()`:

```
SampleClass sample = new SampleClass();

//... Somewhere in the end ...

GC.KeepAlive(sample);
```

Here, `KeepAlive()` creates a reference to your instance of the class in order to garbage collection think, that he still in use in your application. The purpose of the `KeepAlive()` is to ensure the existence of a reference to an object that is at risk of being prematurely reclaimed by the `GC`.

Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method references the obj parameter, making that object ineligible for garbage collection from the start of the routine to the point, in execution order, where this method is called. `Code this method at the end, not the beginning, of the range of instructions where obj must be available.`
>
> The `KeepAlive` method performs no operation and produces no side effects other than extending the lifetime of the object passed in as a parameter.

Alternatively, information can be stored in the WPF-application settings. Especially if the information is important and should not be lost after system failure or reboot.

Settings located approximately here `Project -> Properties -> Parameters`. Example with setting new value:

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.MyButtonColor = "Red";
```

Saving is performed as follows:

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

It also possible using `Binding` with properties, indicating class of the settings in `Source`:

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                          Path=MyButtonColor,
                          Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

For more information about using settings in WPF, please see:

[`User settings in WPF`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx)

[`A configurable Window for WPF`](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/12/27/a-configurable-window-for-wpf/)

[Saving user color settings of a clicked Button in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193207/saving-user-color-settings-of-a-clicked-button)

Answer (score 3):

I belive what you can do is to write a class which would hold variables for you as the session object does in ASP .net . You can do something like

```
public static class ApplicationState
{
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _values =
               new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public static void SetValue(string key, object value)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _values.Remove(key);
        }
        _values.Add(key, value);
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(string key)
    {
        if (_values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return (T)_values[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

To save a variable:

```
ApplicationState.SetValue("MyVariableName", "Value");
```

To read a variable:

```
MainText.Text = ApplicationState.GetValue<string>("MyVariableName");
```

This would be accesses all through yuor application and would remain in memory throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create static class and reference it in xaml like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static double SomeVariable { get { return 1.0; } }
    }
}
```

Then access it from xaml like this:

```
<UserControl Width="{x:Static globals:Globals.SomeVariable}" />
```

where `globals` is defined at top top of your xaml like following:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:globals="clr-namespace:MyNamespace">
</Window>
```